# Select specific subdomain from URL in database

Tags: php, mysql, regex, preg-match

First all, I'm not sure what the correct title I'm suppose to give for my question. Feel free to change it.

Let's say I have 4 URL in database.

```
http://joomla.mywebsite.net/3968923121/2412583825325/
http://www.joomla.mywebsite.net.talleresbanfield.com.ar/cadastrar/index.html
http://belowel.com.joomla.mywebsite.net/images/6058873435/1432583285194/
http://test.com.datacity.mywebsite.net/images/joomla.mywebsite.net/
```

How do I only select this 2 URL

```
http://joomla.mywebsite.net/3968923121/2412583825325/
http://belowel.com.joomla.mywebsite.net/images/6058873435/1432583285194/
```

From given user input `joomla.mywebsite.net` . I could use `LIKE %...%` during `SELECT` but all 4 URL will be selected. I only need to display the URL which correctly use `joomla.mywebsite.net` as it's subdomain.

I'm thinking about selecting all URL first, assign in into array and doing preg_match or regex to do the matching but does it efficient as doing one way query during select?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are perhaps a million ways you can do that. You can also print them out, put them in bottles, throw them in the ocean, just enough of those, wait a little and call some friends on the other side of the ocean which first two they did found. So really, it's hard to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT url
FROM t1
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(url,'/',3) LIKE '%joomla.mywebsite.net'
```

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03e05a/17)

By using **[SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)** like this, you're comparing this part of the strings:

```
http://joomla.mywebsite.net
http://www.joomla.mywebsite.net.talleresbanfield.com.ar
http://belowel.com.joomla.mywebsite.net
http://test.com.datacity.mywebsite.net
```

Basically the URL up to the 3rd `/`

Comment: hi, so I add another incorrect URL `http://hasjid5.comjoomla.mywebsite.net/bevoq/sygxgpmh.php` here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8d3e/1 and the incorrect subdomain got match in the list. Any idea to correct this? Thanks for introducing me to sqlfiddle btw..

Comment: @sg552 well, for that you could do something like this: `WHERE substring_index(url,'/',3) like '%.joomla.mywebsite.net'
OR substring_index(url,'/',3) like '%/joomla.mywebsite.net'` see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8d3e/6

Comment: I don't have your kind of logic. thank you.

Comment: @sg552 Hey don't worry, just keep it up, and keep in mind that thinking outside the box is usually useful...